# Display only something

Tags: gams-math

can we have the display command with certain conditions ,

For example, if we want to just print things their value are bigger than 7 . in other word how can we have

```
   Display $( x.val> 7)
```

In general, is it possible to have condition  on display command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the $ condition on a Display statement like in any, e.g., assignment statement:

```
Scalar x /2/;

Display$(x>3) 'X is greater than 3';
Display$(x>1) 'X is greater than 1';
```