# How Display some of 2 dimension parameter?

Tags: gams-math

I have a parameter  t(i,j) , and set i,j /1*100/ , I want to display only positive t(I,j) .

My try

```
  Display$(t(I,j)>0), t;
```

I read  following answer too [Display only something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783645/display-only-something/51783731#51783731)

When I write my command  like abow answer , I have error

```
  " uncontrolled set entered as constant "
```

What code should I write?

Thanks & Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Display statement with with a symbol will always show the whole symbol. The $ condition you saw in the other post, can only be used to decide, if it should be displayed completely or not at all. You could define a second parameter with just the positive values and display it like this:

```
Set       i /1*100/,
          j /1*100/;
Parameter t(i,j);

t(i,j) = uniformInt(-50,50);

Parameter tPos(i,j);

tPos(i,j)$(t(i,j)>0) = t(i,j);

Display tPos;
```

Comment: Hi.  My understanding of your answer is that: In general, we can not use the display command directly when we have multi dimensional parameters with special conditions (for example display only p>3 for p(I,j) ).  Is this true?

Comment: You can use a condition also for multi dimensional parameters, butthis will either result in showing nothing, or the complete symbol. E.g. you could have a condition saying, show the (complete) symbol p only, if the maximum of all values of p is greater than 3.