# Not Belongs to set

Tags: gams-math

I have  3 set , I want to know what element not belong to 
 Symmetric difference set.

Set1={1*125}

Set2={20*450}

Set3={45*235}

I show the  symmetric difference of setA and  set B by SymAB.

I calculate sym12,sym13,sym23. I have  one if statement, like this ( if element x is not belong to symAB then  display x)

How can I code this conditional statement?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display just parts of a symbol. You can just use a condition to define, if you want to show a symbol or not, see also here: [How Display some of 2 dimension parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164228/how-display-some-of-2-dimension-parameter)

What you could do in your case is to define a symbol with all elements, which are not in the other symbol and display it, if it is not empty, like this:

```
Set x            /1*4/
    symAB        /2,4/
    notSymAB(x);
notSymAB(x) = not SymAB(x);
Display$(card(notSymAB)>0) notSymAB;
```